# Receiving more money to my bank

Tags: salary

I left my job 4 months ago, but my previous employer still paying the salary to my bank account, what should I do?

Comment: A key thing here is to not go on a shopping spree and spend this extra money. You will be asked to remit it back to the company if it is shown that they actually issued extra pay checks to you.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:
a) Calculate how much was overpaid
b) Be sure to have that money available to be able to pay it back quickly
c) Contact you old employer, explain the situation and ask what to do.

Comment: It may worth creating a new bank account for your current income and expenditures. so that the old employer deposits become the only activity on the old account. That way, it will be easy to segregate and avoid spending the erroneous payments.

Comment: I disagree with the order. The first thing to do is notify the employer, everything else comes after that. If he does not have the money at hand, a settlement of time of devolution may be negotiated (after all, it was the employer's mistake). But delaying the notification because the OP does not have right now the money to return to the employer means that he will be acting in bad faith.